# Trying to Map Over an Array within Array and display in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sequelize.js

I currently have three tables in my db. I have a User, Medicine, and Medicine details table. They are related like so, med details belong to medicine and medicine belongs to user.

I am currently using sequelized to call to my db and get the user and the nested tables that belong to the user. In **react** I need to `map` over the Medicine array in the object to get back all the medicine names, then I want to `map` over the med details array to get time they were taken.

```
                <tbody>
                    { user.Medicines && user.Medicines.length !== 0 && user.Medicines.map(item => {
                        console.log(item)
                    

                        const medDeets = item.MedDeets
                        const medDeetMap = medDeets.map(deet => {
                            const time = deet.timeTaken

                            // setTime(time)
             Issue here>?           }) 
                        return (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{item.medicineName}</td>
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>{item.waitingPeriod} hours</td>
                            </tr>

                        )
                        // }


                    })}
                </tbody>
```

If I try to move the `})` from my second `map` function (also shown in code above) I hit what seems to scoping issue and can no longer see the data from my first `map` function. If I try to `setState` from the second `map` function I get a too many rerender error.

Currently a new graduate of a full stack dev program and this is my first time on **Stackoverflow** so sorry if Im missing something obvious. Appreciate the help/feedback.

Comment: Whenever you do setState your component is rendered. So if you write directly setState in render method you will have an infinite loop.

Comment: Try not to do too much inline logic in jsx.  Prepare an array with the data you want to display, then just map it in jsx. Maybe the preparation should be placed in a `useMemo()`  if its expensive.

Answer (score 0):

> You can not `setstate` inside render function because it will cause
> side effect. What exactly happens is that each time you update `state`
> react calls `render` function, so if you will update `state` inside `render`
> function then it will stuck inside infinite loop

```
 <tbody>
                    { user.Medicines && user.Medicines.length !== 0 && user.Medicines.map(item => {
                        console.log(item)
                    

                        const medDeets = item.MedDeets
                        const medDeetMap = medDeets.map(deet => {
                            const time = deet.timeTaken
return time ;
                    }) 
                        return (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{medDeetMap .medicineName}</td>
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>{medDeetMap .waitingPeriod} hours</td>
                            </tr>

                        )
                        // }


                    })}
                </tbody>
```

Comment: Sorry I think my description was a little unclear. I am trying to get the data from the second medDeets.map and display it in the blank <td> sections below.

``` 
<tr>
                                <td>{data from first map}</td>
                                <td>  {data from second map} </td>
                                <td>{data from second map}</td>
                                <td>{data from first map} hours</td>
                            </tr>
```

Comment: you can define a method and setstate there and use state inside the render method